Hostnames being resolved to incorrect IPs on WSL
oreo@laptop:/mnt/c/Users/azhan$ curl google.com -v
*   Trying 216.239.36.10:80...
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4007:814::200e:80...
* Immediate connect fail for 2607:f8b0:4007:814::200e: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2001:4860:4802:36::a:80...
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:4860:4802:36::a: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2001:4860:4802:38::a:80...
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:4860:4802:38::a: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2001:4860:4802:34::a:80...
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:4860:4802:34::a: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2001:4860:4802:32::a:80...
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:4860:4802:32::a: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2001:4860:4802:36::a:80...
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:4860:4802:36::a: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2001:4860:4802:38::a:80...
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:4860:4802:38::a: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2001:4860:4802:34::a:80...
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:4860:4802:34::a: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2001:4860:4802:32::a:80...
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:4860:4802:32::a: Network is unreachable
^C
oreo@laptop:/mnt/c/Users/azhan$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.2-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 41143
;; flags: qr rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 9, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             0       IN      A       142.250.72.142
ns3.google.com.         0       IN      A       216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.         0       IN      A       216.239.38.10
ns2.google.com.         0       IN      A       216.239.34.10
ns1.google.com.         0       IN      A       216.239.32.10
ns3.google.com.         0       IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:36::a
ns4.google.com.         0       IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:38::a
ns2.google.com.         0       IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:34::a
ns1.google.com.         0       IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:32::a

;; Query time: 10 msec
;; SERVER: 172.29.0.1#53(172.29.0.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 25 22:03:42 PDT 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 342

If I curl the same webpage repeatedly from WSL, occasionally the hostname will be resolved to the IP of its nameserver instead of the actual host. (Look at the results from dig, the IP that curl tries to connect to - 216.239.36.10 - is clearly NOT correct; it should be connecting to 142.250.72.142, which is what it does ~90% of the time!)
This is not a curl-specific problem as wget and ping also exhibit the same behavior. I am at a loss for why this is happening. What might cause this? Sorry if I have missed something obvious.

Is 172.29.0.1 the WSL host system? The dig output shows all of the 'additional section' data being in the answer section somehow, which feels like a bug in the DNS proxy that Windows provides... assuming that DNS lookups directly against your LAN DNS server's IP address are unaffected?

It is, and I've just checked and confirmed that my LAN's DNS servers return all records in the appropriate section. So it looks like the Windows DNS proxy is misbehaving.

I managed to fix the issue by blocking WSL from autogenerating resolv.conf via wsl.conf and then manually specifying nameservers to use.
wsl.conf:
[network]
generateResolvConf = false

resolv.conf:
nameserver 1.1.1.1

Even after setting generateResolvConf to false the file kept getting deleted at startup, only after making it immutable with chattr was the problem resolved.
